# push notification is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, push-notification

I'm trying to enable push notification in my app but it's not working. How ever it was working in my last app. When i integrated it in that app. but now i again test that app it's not working in that app also. By  mean of not working is that it's not showing the confirmation or enabling pop view for push notification.i am using 4.6 xcode version and using this line of code for enabling the push notification

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

is there is some issue in new xcode or sdk or there is some change in the code now ?

Comment: are u testing on a new device or the older device u tested in ur last app?

Comment: Use an alert view in this method - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

Comment: Have you enabled push notifications in the provisioning profile and built the app to use it?

Comment: is the provisioning profile matter ? i mean i am using the wild card provisioning profile for testing the push notification

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only once you get the notification to enable the PushNotification . i.e the notification which is showing the message "Would you like to enable the notification ........." . Once you click **OK** on one device you didn't get that same alert on same device on next run . So try to check it on other device or debug the code using the Developer Profile .

Comment: i am check on the new device on which the app is not installed yet so it should come on that app but it not coming after posting this i check that i am missing to integrate the delegates of push notification so i integrated that too but it's not working again after  defining the delegates

Comment: ok Just go to settings->Notifications in your device . If you find your app in that notification center that means the push notification enabled properly or else there is some thing wrong

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate methods log the error in did fail method and verify

```
   - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {
       // other setup tasks here....
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }

    // Delegation methods
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
        const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];
        self.registered = YES;
        [self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes]; // custom method
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
        NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> is the provisioning profile matter ? i mean i am using the wild card
>   provisioning profile for testing the push notification

Yes, the provisioning profile matters. It must contain a push entitlement for the environment to which you intend to send push notifications (either sandbox or production).

From the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) :

> The Team Admin or Team Agent must next create the provisioning profile
>   (Development or Distribution) used in the server side of
>   remote-notification development. The provisioning profile is a
>   collection of assets that associates developers of an application and
>   their devices with an authorized development team and enables those
>   devices to be used for testing. The profile contains certificates,
>   device identifiers, the application’s bundle ID, and all entitlements,
>   including `<aps-environment>`. All team members must install the
>   provisioning profile on the devices on which they will run and test
>   application code.

And you can't use a wild card provisioning profile. You must use a provisioning profile with a non-wildcard Application ID.

From the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) :

> The next page displays your valid application IDs. An application ID
>   consists of an application’s bundle ID prefixed with a ten-character
>   code generated by Apple. The team admin must enter the bundle ID. For
>   a certificate, it must incorporate a specific bundle ID; you cannot
>   use a “wildcard” application ID.

Comment: thanks i have the issue with the provisioning profile i was using the wild card provisioning profile that's why the pop up was not appearing so i made the new provisioning profile having push notification enable thanks man